# yshift of a boxed title doesn't recognize an ex or em length

Tags: tcolorbox

I realized that if you put the length here:

```
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=<length>}
```

in `pt`, `mm` or `cm`, the title box is shifted.

If you put it in `ex` or `em`, it is not.

Is it a `tcolorbox` bug?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My title, 
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-40pt},
    ]
    With \texttt{pt} (or \texttt{mm}, or \texttt{cm}) the positioning works
\end{tcolorbox}

\vspace{30pt}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My title, 
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-4ex},
    ]
    With \texttt{ex} (or \texttt{em}) it doesn't work
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works it's just not that useful.

`em` is a font specific length and without tracing all the code you can take a guess of the font in force at that point if you add

```
\def\nullfont{\ERROR}
```

before the box then you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\nullfont ->\ERROR 

l.11
```

which isn't that useful other than it tells you that `\nullfont` is being used.

`\nullfont` is a built in font with no characters and 1em is 0pt....

Comment: it is in `\pgf@picture`. Patching it to remove the `\nullfont` makes the `yshift` work, but there is extra horizontal shift (of the whole thing and even more of the title) presumably from space tokens.

Comment: Ah, so it's like setting `0pt`, but why does it normally work in `tikz`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I refer you to the last sentence of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97556/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle trying to squeeze some extra rep by posting that link?

Comment: It doesn't work in normal tikz either (for the same reason). Try e.g. `xxx \tikz{\coordinate(a) at (0,0);\draw[green] ([yshift=4mm]a)--++(2,0);\draw[red] ([yshift=4em]a)--++(2,0);}`. It works inside nodes as there a font is active.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: the following works. But depending on the order things are executed in the entrails of `tcolorbox` and `tikz`, it may fail in other cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newdimen\myex
\newcommand*{\getex}{\global\myex=1ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My title\getex, 
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-10.2\myex},
    ]
    With \texttt{1ex} stored in the title it works
\end{tcolorbox}

\vspace{30pt}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My title, 
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-10.2\myex},
    ]
    \getex With \texttt{1ex} stored in the text it works
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]