# Suggest a Practical Roadmap to becoming a TeX/LaTeX expert

Tags: packages, tex-core, latex3, author

What would be a Practical and Optimal Roadmap for a beginner to becoming an expert author or maintainer of a complex and professional `LaTeX` package?

Comment: Suggestion: 1) Master LaTeX. 2) Improve this skill by following and solving questions here. 3) Try your first package. 4) Team up with more advanced LaTeX users for your desired package. // Guessed time-horizon: certainly 2 years hands-on, at least, IF you skip #4.

Comment: IMHO, the path to becoming an expert is actually always the same, regardless of the specialist area: Read, read, read, experiment, read, read, read, ask questions, read, read, read and then do it all over again and again and …

Comment: @cabohah your list is missing "answer questions".

Comment: @cabohah so egreg is no expert, he doesn't ask questions...

Comment: @Skillmon In our days he does not ask TeX questions. But in our days, he is already an expert, so he does not need to ask questions any longer. If he has become an expert without ever asking a question, he would simply be the exception that proves the rule. But presumably he at least asked himself questions. I do it all the time - for example: Why do I write so much nonsense?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is part of "experiment" and the dots.

Comment: @cabohah another way  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5713/963

Comment: @cabohah sorry, I thought it was obvious that this was a joke.

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry, I'm a Postillon reader.